# How to hide a div if the form state is invalid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone suggest me how to hide a div if the form state is invalid??

Actually my requirement is like this:-
I need to display some success bar while page loading & then I want to hide this div if the form state is invalid when the user clicks on submit button.I have tried this, which worked previously but somehow our UI is changed. So, when i try to integrate this code with new UI, its not working.

```
<div class="addUser_success">
</div>
<button class="addUser_button" type="submit" onclick="hideDiv()"></button>
```

Script Code:-

```
function hideDiv() 
   {           
       if (document.getElementById) {
           document.getElementById('addUser_success').style.display = 'none';
   }
```

Also i used Jquery, but doesn't work at all

My Jquery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $(".addUser_button").click(function () 
        {
            alert("hai1");
            $(".addUser_success").hide();
        });
    });
Any code snippets please????
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Instead of `onclick` in submit button you should use `onsubmit` in the form element ... also , attaching event in HTML is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

div.style.display = 'none';

and

div.style.display = 'block';

Comment: Thanks for such response.However i did it by some other way

Comment: As i dont have the right to post my answer now i am not posting. Thank you once again. I will post my answer 2morrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such response.However i did it by some other way

Comment: As i dont have the right to post my answer now i am not posting. Thank you once again. I will post my answer 2morrow.